# How to get Firebase Auth Token without using Task Listeners?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Retrofit 2 and before Firebase Auth I used to store my token in `SharedPreferences` and in my `HttpInterceptor`

```
@Named("rest_api")
@Singleton
@Provides
Interceptor provideRESTInterceptor(final UserManager userManager) {
    return new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(final Chain chain) throws IOException {
            final Request original = chain.request();

            Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .header("Authorization", "XXXX " + sharedPreference.getToken())
                    .method(original.method(), original.body())
                    .build();

            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            return response;
        }
    };
}
```

How could i achieve something like this with
`FirebaseUser.getToken(false/true)` ? I don't know how to wait for the listener callback and than process the request with firebase token.

I am also thinking to check for token validity in here and if its about to expire `getToken(true)`

Comment: Hi @bikash. What do you use instead of "XXXX " so the solution would work?

Comment: I have used the solution given by @Benoit, So far its working good, You may try that too

Comment: Thanks, but I tried and the token is not being accepted. When I saw your answer, I appended  "Bearer " to it and I got a different response but still Unauthorized, so I was wondering what you put instead of "XXXX ".

Comment: That's where your bearer should go, You should check your api requirement, Say if your company name is Google than Google "token", Which Api are you trying to call ?

Comment: There is no API requirement. Its a personal project and Im quite new to HTTPS requests

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure to understand the whole problem, but to wait for the listener callback (in other words, making a synchronous method out of an asynchronous call) can be achieved like this :

```
private String getToken() {
    final StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder() ;
    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1) ;
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
            token.append(task.getResult().getToken());
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    });
    try {
        countDownLatch.await(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return token.toString() ;
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        return null;            
    }
}
```

Notes :

- StringBuilder is just used here as a String holder.
- Bullet-proof implementation should of course check task.isSuccessful()
- Timeout (here 30 sec) should be adapted to your situation

Hope this helps.

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for, i have just modified the code to first get the cache token with boolean set as false, then if its expiry is near than call again with boolean set to true to get the refresh token